# Message Screen perform message count and if message read then not count and show message

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

In the message screen functionality, if the user has viewed the message, the message should be displayed as counted in the message screen, and if the user has viewed the message, the message should not be counted.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fitN9.png)

In this image you can see that there are two messages in the message screen, if the user has not seen them, then it shows that the messages have been counted. And if the user has viewed the message then it shows the message not counted. And if the user in front is typing the message then the message should appear as typing in the screen.

This is my send chat button code

```
@IBAction func btnActionMsgSend(_ sender: Any) {
    if (txtMsg.text == "" || txtMsg.text == " ") {
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Alert", message: "Please type a Message", preferredStyle: UIAlertController.Style.alert)
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertAction.Style.default, handler: nil))
        self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
    else {
        let database = Database.database().reference()
        
        let str =  "\(String(describing: self.getCurrentTimeStamp().replacingOccurrences(of: ".", with: "")))" + "_" + "\(String(describing: Auth.auth().currentUser!.uid))" + "_" + "\(String(describing: dict.object(forKey: "userid")!))"
        
        database.child("Chats").child("\(String(describing: dict.object(forKey: "userid")!))").child(Auth.auth().currentUser!.uid).updateChildValues([str : txtMsg.text!])
        
        database.child("Chats").child(Auth.auth().currentUser!.uid).child("\(String(describing: dict.object(forKey: "userid")!))").updateChildValues([str : txtMsg.text!])
        
        self.tblChat.reloadData()
        
        txtMsg.text = " "
    }
}
```

Here is my real time database to store button action event action messages:

[image]

Comment: It’s a good idea to include code, errors and and structures as *text*, not links and images. That way, if they are needed in an answer, they can be copied and pasted. Also, if the links break, it would invalidate the question. To get your Firebase structure, use the Firebase console->Export JSON and copy and paste a snippet of your structure. Take a look at [No Images Please](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: Also, the question is a bit vague. Are you having difficulty with the presented code? If so, what's the trouble? What line is not behaving as expected. If you're asking something else, please clarify.